# Project Euler Problem 33 - digit canceling fractions

Tags: python, optimization, programming-challenge

> **Problem:**
>
> The fraction \$(\dfrac{49}{98})\$ is a curious fraction, as an inexperienced
>   mathematician in attempting to simplify it may incorrectly believe
>   that \$(\dfrac{49}{98}) = (\dfrac{4}{8})\$, which is correct, is obtained by cancelling the 9s.
>
> We shall consider fractions like, \$(\dfrac{30}{50}) = (\dfrac{3}{5})\$, to be trivial examples.
>
> There are exactly four non-trivial examples of this type of fraction,
>   less than one in value, and containing two digits in the numerator and
>   denominator.
>
> If the product of these four fractions is given in its lowest common
>   terms, find the value of the denominator.

This is some rough code -- this one was a lot harder than I expected it to be. Please help me optimize.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
fractions_that_work = []

def a_common_element(list_a, list_b):
    count = 0
    common = 0
    for m in list_a:
        for n in list_b:
            if m == n:
                count += 1
                common = m
    if count == 1:
        return common
    return False

for numerator in range(10, 100):
    for denominator in range(numerator + 1, 100): # denom must be > num
        n_digits = sorted([int(x) for x in str(numerator)])
        d_digits = sorted([int(x) for x in str(denominator)])
        common = a_common_element(n_digits, d_digits)
        if common:
            n_digits.remove(common)
            d_digits.remove(common)
            n_rem = n_digits[0]
            d_rem = d_digits[0]
            if 0 not in n_digits and 0 not in d_digits:
                if float(numerator) / denominator == float(n_rem) / d_rem:
                    fractions_that_work.append([numerator, denominator])        
product_of_fractions = [1, 1]
for frac in fractions_that_work:
    product_of_fractions[0] *= frac[0]
    product_of_fractions[1] *= frac[1]

start = timer()
ans = product_of_fractions[1] / product_of_fractions[0]
elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000 # s --> ms

print "Found %d in %r ms." % (ans, elapsed_time)
```

Comment: Note for reviewers : the `start = timer()` is a mistake. Keeping the code in the answer as it is unless a mod thinks it's better to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you set `start` at the top of the script (which is OK). However, you **reset** `start` right before your final calulation:

```
# This will only time the execution of one statement!
start = timer()
ans = product_of_fractions[1] / product_of_fractions[0]
elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000 # s --> ms
```

Remove the above `start = timer()` to get a more accurate timing. Also, I would recommend moving the first `start` declaration to just before the nested `for` loops. That was the start time is more *spatially* related to what you are actually timing.

---

Secondly, your `a_common_element` function's name is a little misleading. Currently, it insinuates it will return positively if the two `lists` have *any number* of common elements. Changing the function name to something like `has_single_common_element` gives a better description of what the function actually does.

Also, `a_common_element` can be simplified a tad. By using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) we can combine the nested `for` loops into one comprehension:

```
def a_common_element(list_a, list_b):
    common_list = [value for value in list_a if value in list_b]

    if len(common_list) == 1:
        return common_list[0]
    return False
```

---

Your next section is actually quite interesting: you used a neat way to separate the digits. However, the downfall (I believe) to your method is the back-and-forth casting that it requires. I would, instead, recommend doing to calculations to get your digits:

```
for numerator in range(10, 100):
    for denomerator in range(numerator+1, 100):
        # Division will strip off the first digit
        # Modulus will strip off the 0th digit
        n_digits = sorted([int(numerator/10), numerator % 10])           
        d_digits = sorted([int(denomerator/10), denomerator % 10])
```

NOTE: This recommendation is based on the project description you provided, that is all numbers will have exactly 2 digits. If you wanted to extend this to greater sets of numbers (3-digits, 4-digits, etc) I would keep your current implementation.

---

This next recommendation, like the previous, is based off of 2-digit numbers only.

Once you remove the common digit from the `lists`, you assign the remaining digits to variables; which is good. However, you then go check if the `lists` contain `0` instead of comparing the variables:

```
# I imagine this is what Python does in the backgroud when you say:
#    if 0 not in list
if n_rem != 0 and d_rem != 0:
```

---

Your next section is nice. Its simple and intuitive. If you wanted to make the code more Pythonic, you could instead do it this way:

```
product_of_fractions = [1, 1]
for frac in fractions_that_work:
    product_of_fractions = [i*j for i, j in zip(product_of_fractions, frac)]
```

If you wanted to go a bit more towards functional programming you could use this single line of code:

```
from functools import reduce   # Needed for Python 3, works in Python 2.6+
import operator

product_of_fractions = [reduce(operator.mul, value) for value in zip(*fractions_that_work)]
```

Even though it may be more complex (and thus slightly less readable), I prefer this last way because of its brevity.